# Build a bash command with conditional parameters and cuote parameters

Tags: bash, arguments

I need to build a bash command in a script depending on some cuote or normal parameters. For example:

```
BAYES)
    class="weka.classifiers.bayes.BayesNet"
    A="-D -Q weka.classifiers.bayes.net.search.local.K2 -- -P 1 -S BAYES -E"
    B="weka.classifiers.bayes.net.estimate.SimpleEstimator -- -A 0.5" ;;
LOGISTIC)
    class="weka.classifiers.functions.Logistic"
    A="-R 1.0E-8 -M -1 -num-decimal-places 4" ;;
SIMPLELOG)
    class="weka.classifiers.functions.SimpleLogistic"
    A="-I 0 -M 500 -H 50 -W 0.0" ;;
SMO)
    class="weka.classifiers.functions.SMO"
    A="-C 1.0 -L 0.001 -P 1.0E-12 -N 0 -V -1 -W 1 -K"
    A1="weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.PolyKernel -C 250007 -E 1.0" ;;
IBK)
    class="weka.classifiers.lazy.IBk"
    A="-K 1 -W 0 -A "
    A1="weka.core.neighboursearch.LinearNNSearch -A"
    A2="weka.core.EuclideanDistance -R first-last" ;;
KSTAR)
    class="weka.classifiers.lazy.KStar"
    A="-B 20 -M a" ;;
...
java -Xmx"$mem"m -cp "$WEKA_INSTALL_DIR/weka.jar"  $class -s $i -t "$file" $A "$A1" $B "$B1"
```

However, my problem is that in some conditions, when $A1 is empty, the "$A1" parameter is not valid. The same with "$B1". And the parameter could be in any combination ($A1 with $B1, $A1 without $B2, ...).

Also I've tried include $A1 in $A as following:

```
A="-C 1.0 -L 0.001 -P 1.0E-12 -N 0 -V -1 -W 1 -K \"weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.PolyKernel -C 250007 -E 1.0\""
```

and execute:

```
java -Xmx"$mem"m -cp "$WEKA_INSTALL_DIR/weka.jar"  $class -s $i -t "$file" $A
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: When I try to use that combination of parameters, weka tell me that the parameter -K has not correct value.

The problem of your approximation is that doesn't resolve my problem. Imagine that a combination of A don't need any extra parameter (for example LOGISTIC), so the command will be:

    `... $class -s $i -t "$file" -R 1.0E-8 -M -1 -num-decimal-places 4 ""`

That "" at the end of the command generates an error of arguments because there is an unexpected extra argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot safely and reliably store multiple arguments in a single string; you need to use arrays; this is their intended use case. Make sure to initialize any arrays that won't be used, so that they "disappear" when expanded.

```
# If A is undefined, "${A[@]}" is an empty string.
# But if A=(), then "${A[@]}" simply disappears from the command line.
A=()
B=()
A1=()
A2=()

case $something in

BAYES)
    class="weka.classifiers.bayes.BayesNet"
    A=(-D -Q weka.classifiers.bayes.net.search.local.K2 -- -P 1 -S BAYES -E)
    B=(weka.classifiers.bayes.net.estimate.SimpleEstimator -- -A 0.5);;
LOGISTIC)
    class="weka.classifiers.functions.Logistic"
    A=(-R 1.0E-8 -M -1 -num-decimal-places 4);;
SIMPLELOG)
    class="weka.classifiers.functions.SimpleLogistic"
    A=(-I 0 -M 500 -H 50 -W 0.0) ;;
SMO)
    class="weka.classifiers.functions.SMO"
    A=(-C 1.0 -L 0.001 -P 1.0E-12 -N 0 -V -1 -W 1 -K)
    A1=(weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.PolyKernel -C 250007 -E 1.0) ;;
IBK)
    class="weka.classifiers.lazy.IBk"
    A=(-K 1 -W 0 -A)
    A1=(weka.core.neighboursearch.LinearNNSearch -A)
    A2=(weka.core.EuclideanDistance -R first-last);;
KSTAR)
    class="weka.classifiers.lazy.KStar"
    A=(-B 20 -M a) ;;
esac
```

and *always* quote parameter expansions.

```
java -Xmx"$mem"m -cp "$WEKA_INSTALL_DIR/weka.jar" \
  "$class" -s "$i" -t "$file" "${A[@]}" "${A1[@]}" "${B[@]}" "${B1[@]}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Using bash array was easier than I thought and I needed only one argument.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

I solved all my problems using only a parameter A like this:

```
BAYES)
    class="weka.classifiers.bayes.BayesNet"
    A=(-D -Q weka.classifiers.bayes.net.search.local.K2 -- -P 1 -S BAYES -E weka.classifiers.bayes.net.estimate.SimpleEstimator -- -A 0.5);;
SMO)
    class="weka.classifiers.functions.SMO"
    A=(-C 1.0 -L 0.001 -P 1.0E-12 -N 0 -V -1 -W 1 -K "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.PolyKernel -C 250007 -E 1.0");;

java -Xmx"$mem"m -cp "$WEKA_INSTALL_DIR/weka.jar"  $class -s $i -t "$file" "${A[@]}"
```

Answer (score -1):

From your question, I did:

- Initialized the variables
- Completed the case statement
- Removed some not required double quotes
- Defined some variables for which you did not provide values for
- backslash your double quotes if you must have then in the java command

If you need double quotes for certain variables, put these in the variables.  This way you will not have "" in your java command if the variables is empty.  I did this for A1 in case IBK.

This will get you started, modify as required:

```
#!/bin/bash
#

mem="512"
WEKA_INSTALL_DIR='/opt/weka'
class=""
i="value-of-i"
A=""
A1=""
B=""
B1=""
file="SOMEFILE"

case $1 in
    'BAYES')
        class="weka.classifiers.bayes.BayesNet"
        A="-D -Q weka.classifiers.bayes.net.search.local.K2 -- -P 1 -S BAYES -E"
        B="weka.classifiers.bayes.net.estimate.SimpleEstimator -- -A 0.5"
        ;;
    'LOGISTIC')
        class="weka.classifiers.functions.Logistic"
        A="-R 1.0E-8 -M -1 -num-decimal-places 4"
        ;;
    'SIMPLELOG')
        class="weka.classifiers.functions.SimpleLogistic"
        A="-I 0 -M 500 -H 50 -W 0.0"
        ;;
    'SMO')
        class="weka.classifiers.functions.SMO"
        A="-C 1.0 -L 0.001 -P 1.0E-12 -N 0 -V -1 -W 1 -K"
        A1="weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.PolyKernel -C 250007 -E 1.0"
        ;;
    'IBK')
        class="weka.classifiers.lazy.IBk"
        A="-K 1 -W 0 -A "
        A1="\"weka.core.neighboursearch.LinearNNSearch -A\""
        A2="weka.core.EuclideanDistance -R first-last"
        ;;
    'KSTAR')
        class="weka.classifiers.lazy.KStar"
        A="-B 20 -M a"
        ;;
    *)
        # default options
        ;;
esac

echo java -Xmx${mem}m -cp $WEKA_INSTALL_DIR/weka.jar  $class -s $i -t $file $A $A1 $B $B1
```

Example:

```
./test.bash LOGISTIC
java -Xmx512m -cp /opt/weka/weka.jar weka.classifiers.functions.Logistic -s value-of-i -t SOMEFILE -R 1.0E-8 -M -1 -num-decimal-places 4

./test.bash IBK
java -Xmx512m -cp /opt/weka/weka.jar weka.classifiers.lazy.IBk -s value-of-i -t SOMEFILE -K 1 -W 0 -A "weka.core.neighboursearch.LinearNNSearch -A"
```

Comment: The problem is not the variable initialization, the problem is the $A1 and $B1 need cuotes "". It will be:

`java -Xmx${mem}m -cp $WEKA_INSTALL_DIR/weka.jar  $class -s $i -t $file $A "$A1" $B "$B1"`

But if a classifier don't need $A1 extra arguments for $A appears a argument error.

Comment: Modified answer, see the case IBK.